# Korrekte Aussprache von 'van Gogh'

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronunciation, political-correctness

In einer [englischen Panelshow wurde](https://youtu.be/HcVw2E0_JUs?t=622) große Freude erzeugt durch die Frage nach *der* 'korrekten' Aussprache des Namens des Malers [Vincent van Gogh](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh). In der deutschen Wikipedia steht: [ɡɔx, niederländisch ɣɔx]. Da es eine deutsche Stadt mit Namen [Goch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goch) in der Nähe der niederländischen Grenze gibt und man 'korrekt' nicht (mehr) *Eger* sagt sondern *[Cheb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheb)* sagt:

1. ist der Name des Künstlers tatsächlich hergeleitet aus der [niederländischen Herkunftsbezeichnung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_(Dutch)): 'aus der Stadt Goch' (hab's nicht verifizieren können)
2. ist die dadurch abzuleitende bevorzugte (derzeitige) deutsche Aussprache daher exakt wie in [Goch (archaic spelling: Gog, Dutch: Gogh)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goch)
3. Sind beim Gebrauch der Möglichkeiten des Namens in den zur Verfügung stehenden Aussprachevarianten (politische) Konnotationen möglich – oder sogar zu erwarten?

Sucht man nach Beispielen im Netz ergibt sich ein sehr uneinheitliches Bild:
[Wie wird der Künstler ausgesprochen? :-)](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/wie-wird-der-kuenstler-ausgesprochen---), [Aussprache Vincent Van Gogh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejJ1KiwnTvg), [Korrekte Aussprache: Vincent van Gogh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngnPiepJYcg), [Wie man Van Gogh ausspricht](https://de.forvo.com/word/van_gogh/), [Wie man Vincent van Gogh ausspricht](https://de.forvo.com/word/vincent_van_gogh/), [Aussprache niederländischer Namen](https://www.buurtaal.de/blog/aussprache-niederlaendischer-namen), [Van Gogh ausgesprochen Van Gok oder Van Goch](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/van-gogh-ausgesprochen-van-gok-oder-van-goch).

Ist es also empfehlenswert den Namen generell niederländisch, niederländisch-eingedeutscht oder deutsch auszusprechen, oder sollten situative Umstände berücksichtigt werden??

---

<sub>Es geht hier nicht um Expertise in einer anderen Sprache als der hiesigen. Es geht ausschließlich um 'normale' deutsche Aussprache, mögliche Varianten in der zu beobachtenden (Hyper-)Korrektheit, mögliche konnotative Implikationen bei der Wahl einer Variante.

Anders gefragt: Wieso unterscheiden sich in der Sprechpräferenz deutscher Sprecher so stabil die Anfangsbuchstaben in van Gogh und van Gaal, was könnte man daraus ableiten?</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72732/discussion-on-question-by-langlangc-korrekte-aussprache-von-van-gogh).

Comment: Was wäre denn eine konnotative Implikation, hast du dazu ein Beispiel oder eine Vermutung? Wer oder was ist denn hyperkorrekt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bei der Aussprache Vincent van Goghs Nachnamens wird nicht die niederländische, sondern die eingedeutschte Variante `[ɡɔx]` bevorzugt. Eine politische Konnotation besteht nicht, es handelt sich um eine Beobachtung der Häufigkeit. So ist diese Aussprache auch zu hören in redaktionell bearbeiteten Beiträgen des öffentlich-rechtlichen Rundfunks, die sich um eine einheitliche Aussprache bemühen. Leider besteht kein allgemeiner Zugriff auf deren [Aussprachdatenbank](http://www.ard.de/home/die-ard/fakten/abc-der-ard/ARD_Aussprachedatenbank____AusspracheDatenBank__ADB__der_ARD/563650/index.html), so dass man sich mit Videoschnipseln der einschlägigen Videoportale und Mediatheken begnügen muss.

Nicht ganz so einheitlich ist die Aussprache des Vornamens, hier dominieren mindestens vier Varianten (vermutlich noch mehr, wenn man noch ein stimmloses oder stimmhaftes `S` dazu nimmt).

Damit ergeben sich folgende Aussprachevarianten:

> **Vincent** `[vɪnʦɛnt]` oder `[vɪnzɛnt]`, seltener auch `[ˈfɪnʦɛnt] [ˈfɪnzɛnt]`
>   **van** `[fan]`
>   **Gogh** `[ɡɔx]`